# Being html_safe in Rails while retaining html entities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-entities, actionview

Let's say I'm outputting a post title and in our database, it's `Hello Y&#8217;all` -- can I output it without using `.html_safe`, but in such a way that it doesn't get output in html as `Hello Y&amp;#8217;all`?

That is, if a user copies a post title from a word processor that uses typographically correct apostrophes, I'm getting gibberish output since it's escaping the `&` in the database as `&amp;`. Of course, I would want a title from the database that's `Bonnie & Clyde` to be output as `Bonnie &amp; Clyde` since that is the correct HTML...

Is there a safe way to do this?

Comment: I don't want to mark it as `.html_safe` or use `raw()` because that opens us up to xss. I just don't want things that are already html entities in my database to be double escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SafeBuffer calls `ERB::Util.h` for strings that aren't `html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html#method-i-concat), so you can `gsub` on `ERB::Util.h(your_string)` and replace instances of `&amp;[code]` with `&[code];` when first saving the string in your database. That way your string is first sanitized

The call you need is `ERB::Util.h(your_string).gsub(/&amp;(#x?[\da-fA-F]+;)/, '&\1')`

Then whenever you need to display that particular string, call `html_safe` on it.

Answer (score 10):

Use [ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)

```
<%= "Hello Y&#8217;all" %>
<%= sanitize "Hello Y&#8217;all" %>
```

will produce:

```
Hello Y&#8217;all
Hello Y’all
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer, but note that by default, `sanitize` allows a subset of HTML tags and attributes. If you do not want to allow these, call it like this: `<%= sanitize("Hello Y&#8217;all", tags: [], attributes: []) %>`. Here is the documentation for `WhitelistSanitizer`, which is the default used: https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer#whitelistsanitizer.

Comment: Thanks Maciej and Stephen, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 ways to do this:

```
1: "string".htmlsafe
2: <%= raw "string" %>
3. <%== "string" %>
```

I think you should use <%= raw "string" %> as it takes the argument, apply .to_s to it, and then it simply apply html_safe to it. Hence it would be safe to use 2nd option.

Comment: I added a comment above--I don't want to use `html_safe` as the user submitted post title could contain malicious code like `<script>alert('foo;')</script>`

Comment: so i think you should use <%= raw "string" %>
as it takes the argument, apply .to_s to it, and then it simply apply html_safe to it. Hence it would be safe to use raw

Comment: i.e. what i am saying, raw applies to_s to argument it get. You can write anything and you will get html_safe from raw, as it first convert the argument to string. So any malicious code will be html_safe

Answer (score 0):

`<%= raw "Y&amp;#8217;all" %>` or `<%== "Y&amp;#8217;all" %>` are two possibilities.

Comment: Sorry, as I said above, I don't want to mark the whole string as html_safe or use raw because the user submitted post title could contain malicious content.